# iOS - How to make custom keyboard extension work with physical keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, bluetooth

I have had this question for a long time and I tried to search it in iOS 10 APIs but I couldn't find any, if anyone knows the corresponding APIs, please help here.

So I have an iOS custom keyboard for Mandarin and it requires selecting word after some inputs.

Google's custom keyboard GBoard now supports Simplified Chinese and it works with iPad Pro Smart Keyboard and it will display a list of candidate words right below the cursor as shown in this video.

[GBoard Simplified Chinese Input](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/717667/gobard.mp4)

But I couldn't find the corresponding API to make this happen for my own custom keyboard extension.

So 2 questions here:

1. Is it doable now to make a custom keyboard extension work for external physical bluetooth keyboard, and how? Not iPad Pro Smart Keyboard but generally using Apple bluetooth keyboard with say an iPad Air.
2. If #1 it not doable now, how can I make my custom keyboard work like GBoard so that when the user types some english chars, the candidate list will appear right below the cursor and then use arrow keys to navigate and enter to input.

Much appreciated.